# Can application server deploy/undeploy apps with same classloader?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jetty, plugin-architecture

**Prerequisites:**
This question doesn't relate to some particular application server. The only condition set is that it is about Java application servers (Tomcat, JBoss, WebSphere etc)

**Question:**
I want to deploy application on application server with one feature: I would like to introduce plugin architecture for it. I.e. I want to deploy my MAIN application in a usual way we do in Tomcat, for example, but then I want to be able to dynamically add MODULES to this application using standart application server functionality. After this operation MAIN application should be able to address classes from MODULE, for example it should be able to instantiate classes by class name, read configs from MODULE jar etc.

Is it possible for some application server?

Comment: That is rather confusing to read (read it 4 times).  Can you simplify and give examples please?

Comment: Sorry! Example: I have deployed my application named 'main' on some application server. I want to add some plugin to this application. By 'plugin' I mean a set of classes. For example, some new implementation of interface, defined in my 'main' application. But then, may be I want to switch plugin 1 off, and replace it with plugin 2 with new implementation of interface from 'main' application. And I dont want plugin 1 classes to remain in memory. I.e. I want to call 'undeploy' for plugin 1. I know its possible in OSGI. Is it possible in some application server?